# Please do not recommend moving an on topic SFF video game identification question to Arqade!

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

Story identification questions are perfectly on topic on SFF and in fact we are one of the main sites that have made them work. Video games are also [on topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/319/58193) for us and we even have a specific [video game story id guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11995/58193).

Now with that established we actually don't get many video game identification questions but when we do they are usually accompanied by some form of comment like:

> You should have asked this on Arqade.

**This is not okay.** Assuming that these questions are SFF-nal and so on topic then asking, or even telling, users that they should ask on Arqade instead is not acceptable. It is up to the OP to ask where they choose and if they choose SFF over Arqade then they clearly want their question there.

What is more troubling is that a lot of these have even requested moving them **when the question has no media in it** and thus it would be closed here. I found it more troublesome recently when a high rep user here suggested that the OP should have asked on reddit when the question was on topic on SFF!

So long story short...

#### Please do not recommend moving an on topic SFF question to Arqade!

---

<sub>*I have deliberately not included examples of these comments but if requested I can find some. Of the last 5, all the ones this year, 3 have a comment and the last 2, most recent, (which inspired me to post this) both have a comment.*</sub>

---

<sub>*I have also posted [something similar on SFF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12398/58193).*</sub>

Comment: Shouldn't this be on SFF instead of here?

Comment: A high rep user here recommended moving a SFF question here so I feel like it's worth mentioning it on both and also from the post _"I have also posted something similar on SFF."_

Comment: @Wrigglenite - In the last couple of instances I've seen these comments posted, the user has been both a member on SFF *and* Arqade.

Comment: I've seen a question, recently, where a high rep Arqade users (30k+) posted without any real rep on SciFi (only having the association bonus amount of rep). In this case, the question as it was *was actually on topic* for SciFi, but was *not* on topic for Arqade.

Answer (score 14):

For a more general rule, the only time we should recommend moving questions between sites is if the question is **off topic** for the current site, but would be a **good, on-topic** question elsewhere.

Some sites overlap a little bit. If a question is on topic for two sites, it is the asker's choice which community they ask on.

The other thing to remember: [Don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82986/179041). Also don't simply 'throw it over the fence': at the very least, have a basic understanding of how the target site works before you recommend migrating a question to it.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the last 5 of your questions on your site with both [story-indentification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-indentification) and [video-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) I agree that no one should be recommending moving them to the Arqade. If any one of those questions were asked here, they would promptly be closed and deleted as they do not meet our [strict guidelines](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/game-identification/info) for [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) questions.

Even if they did have artifacts for their questions they asked on SFF, they still shouldn't be migrated here if they are on topic on SFF. I don't think very many people from the Arqade will be upset that they won't get migrated here, as a large portion of our user base do not like those types of questions at all, and would prefer if they were banned altogether from our site.

I also looked at the comments on the questions, and only saw one comment left by a high rep user here. I assume they did not know about your policy regarding these questions. I would recommend in the future linking your policy for these questions to inform the person that they are indeed on topic for your site, and flagging their comment suggesting migration as No Longer Needed.

Comment: Regarding linking the policy, another user had already replied to that user stating these questions are fine on SFF. The immediate "problem" (for lack of a better word) was already taken care of. I just wanted to post this as more of a permanent reminder.