# My game identification question was closed as off-topic. Where can I ask for help instead?

Tags: discussion, faq, closing, game-identification

I posted a game identification question which was closed as off-topic because it was lacking a screenshot or video from the game I'm trying to identify. Is there anywhere else I can ask my question if I don't have any artifacts from the game?

---

This FAQ is part of a follow-up to [this proposal](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13490/143571) in our 2019 Community Check-in. Please post one suggestion per answer, stating any relevant information such as how to use it or the rules of its community.

Comment: Related: [What are Arqade's requirements for asking a Game Identification Question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10197/28182)

Comment: Thanks Arqade (and wider SE) members, we've got some good suggestions here! We're taking this out of [featured] now, but that doesn't mean this FAQ should remain static forever. Just like regular Stack Exchange questions/answers: if you have more suggestions as other services crop up (even years later), please, don't hesitate to post them below (and flag answers where the service is no longer active for deletion). This FAQ is only useful so long as it's up to date, so let's keep it that way! :)

Comment: Possibly also mention Eric S. Raymond's [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) (with the reminder requested in the Disclaimer section).

Answer (score 20):

## [/r/tipofmyjoystick](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/)

[**/r/tipofmyjoystick**](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/) is a subreddit dedicated to answering game identification questions and allows identification questions without any sort of assets. Before posting there, make sure to read their [guide to better results](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/comments/64i787/psa_a_guide_to_better_results/) and the [subreddit's rules](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/about/rules).

Answer (score 14):

If the game you remember has a clear Science Fiction, Fantasy, or other [Speculative Fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_fiction) theme, then you can ask on our sister-site:

## [Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)

Please see their helpful video game identification guide: [How to ask a good (video game) story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11995/11061) and also their general ID guide [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193), and remember that Stack Exchange's [Code of Conduct](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/conduct) applies there, too.

Comment: And remember, [don't migrate crap](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13300/124566) ;)

Comment: This should explain the scope briefly, but I'm not sure how to do this concisely—our scope decisions on SFF are spread throughout over 300 questions.

Answer (score 11):

## The Bridge

If you have at least [20 reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat), you're welcome to join us in [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), Arqade's main chat room. Most of the regulars have played quite a few games, and might be able to identify the game you're looking for just from the description.

Remember that [our Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies and, since this is a chat room, messages can get lost in the flow. Don't repeat your question too quickly if you don't receive an answer, but it's fine to ask again after a few hours in order to reach different people who might live in different timezones.

Comment: Although at the point of asking in chat, the primary value of StackExchange has been lost, chiefly that it is readily searchable and similar questions can be found. It would actually be better to find a Discord channel to ask in (or, as other say, reddit).

Answer (score 5):

## /r/flashgames

https://old.reddit.com/r/FlashGames/

A subreddit dedicated to the discussion of Flash games as well as identifying flash games.  Similar to /r/tipofmyjoystick but more focused within Flash games specifically.

Answer (score 4):

## The "What was that game called" Thread on Kongregate

https://www.kongregate.com/forums/3-general-gaming/topics/57132-the-what-was-that-game-called-thread?page=1

If you have a Kongregate account or have a browser game you wish to inquire about, you might have some luck asking people in this thread, Since Kongregate is a browser game portal.

Answer (score 2):

## `#identify-a-game` on the MobyGames Discord

[MobyGames](https://www.mobygames.com/) is a site dedicated to cataloguing video/computer/mobile/etc. games and their public Discord (accessible from the site footer) has a channel dedicated to this kind of question, similar to /r/TipOfMyJoystick.

I also contributed a "please answer as many of these as possible when asking your question" guide, which is currently at the top of the pinned messages panel.