# Could we add links to the Meta posts created to redirect users to external sources for off-topic questions to the relevant help page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, allowed-questions, help-center

A couple months ago, I suggested we created several Meta posts for our default off-topic close reasons so we can redirect users to a location where that particular question is on-topic and users are willing to answer the question. This suggestion was very well received, and as far as I know, these questions have already been created and added to the relevant close reasons.

Now, these questions have been added to the relevant close reasons, but I've noticed they are missing on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, where all close reasons are clearly listed. Assuming we have the room to fit them on that page, I think it would make sense to also add these listings of alternative resources to this page too.

As a feature request, I'd like to suggest we add a link to each list we made to that resource. Is that feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good idea. I've gone ahead and updated that page with the added information.

> Please note, however, that site policies *prohibit* questions
>   of the following types:
>
> - Game and Mod Development (try the [Game Development Stack
>     Exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) instead)
> - Speculations on future of the industry, upcoming (but unreleased) games or content, and developer intent on mechanics and
>     narrative
> - Requests for game identification based on personal recollection alone.  Read here
>     for more information on the close reason, and read here
>     for some helpful tips on how to identify a game when we can't
>     help.
> - Recommendations for software, hardware, games, or genres. See My
>     request for recommendations was closed as off-topic. Where can I ask
>     for help instead?
> - Piracy, and support with pirated games
> - Troubleshooting and diagnosis of [modded
>     Minecraft](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no), including crashes, startup errors or other abnormal
>     behaviour caused by modding. See Where can I ask technical troubleshooting questions about modded Minecraft?

Comment: I'm fairly sure we also had a meta question about where to ask Game ID questions.

Comment: @Nzall I believe that's [My game identification question was closed as off-topic. Where can I ask for help instead?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13525/4797)