# Game ID questions in SE

Tags: discussion, game-identification

So as we all know, Arcade doesn't allow Game ID without some kind of resource (image, video clip, etc) to help the answerer correctly identify the game in question.

However, I saw [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/237653/46407) on SF&F.

The question is two part:

1. Is the criteria posted in the question enough for us to answer the question?
2. Should we endorse this? If a question does not provide adequate detail for *us* to answer, should we suggest they try over on SF&F instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My game identification question was closed as off-topic. Where can I ask for help instead?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13525/my-game-identification-question-was-closed-as-off-topic-where-can-i-ask-for-hel)

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what you mean by question 1 - it doesn't fit our guidelines, no. But if it works for them and their site rules about such things, and you want to answer there, go ahead? Sorry, I am just not quite sure what you mean there.

Are we sure they want all of our questions like that to be pointed to them? Do they fit their guidelines? Are all video games valid as SF/F? I don't think we can clearly answer that. I mean as always, you don't want to migrate bad questions to another site, they're not our home for reject questions. Just because they have allowed this one so far doesn't mean we should blanket suggest everyone go there without making sure we understand their approach.