# Game identification question based on description from memory

Tags: support, allowed-questions, game-identification

I was hoping to ask a [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) question, basing my description of the text-based RPG on memory. But the tag description states:

> Only ask if you have a screenshot, video, or audio clip from the game
> you want to identify. This tag is only for identifying games in
> movies, pictures, videos, advertisements or otherwise where an unknown
> game appears - not from a description of what you can recall from
> memory, or from a picture you drew yourself.

Is this type of question appropriate *anywhere* on this site, or on-topic on any other Stack Exchange site?

Comment: I just realized why people are confused by this tag, so thank you for asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My game identification question was closed as off-topic. Where can I ask for help instead?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13525/my-game-identification-question-was-closed-as-off-topic-where-can-i-ask-for-hel)

Answer (score 5):

Game identification questions are only allowed when you have a screenshot, video, or anything beyond a description. The wording "This tag is only for identifying games in movies, pictures, videos, advertisements or otherwise where an unknown game appears" doesn't make that clear, so I've changed the tag excerpt to:

> Only ask if you have a screenshot, video, or audio clip from the game you want to identify. The only game identification questions allowed on this site are those asking to identify games in movies, pictures, videos, advertisements or otherwise where an unknown game appears - not from a description of what you can recall from memory, or from a picture you drew yourself.

While we can't help you within our Q&A format, the [Game Identification tag wiki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/game-identification/info) contains information on how to organize your thoughts into a good game identification question from memory that you can ask elsewhere. We also have a community-curated list of additional resources where you can ask for help in this question: [My game identification question was closed as off-topic. Where can I ask for help instead?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13525/143571)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this type of question […] on-topic on any other Stack Exchange site?

##### If the game has a Speculative Fiction theme, then yes, it's on-topic at [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com).

If you are looking to identify a video game with a [Speculative Fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_fiction) theme (such as Sci-Fi, Fantasy, Horror, Superhero Fiction, Alternate History, Supernatural Fiction, and the like), you may want to ask your question on our sister site [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com). They accept identification questions for Speculative Fiction works in any medium, including video games, based on descriptions from memory. Any relevant media you can provide, including sketches or drawings, would help.

Please make sure to read their [identification guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957) and [video games–specific identification guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11995/7957) before posting. You can also check out [some of the questions there tagged [story-identification] and [video-games]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification%2Bvideo-games?tab=Votes) for some examples of how to format your question and what kind of details to include.

Relevant Science Fiction & Fantasy SE Meta posts:

- [Are all questions about games on-topic as long as they contain some SciFi or Fantasy element?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4776/7957)
- [How to ask a good (video game) story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11995/7957)
- [Game Identification Questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13392/7957)
- [Would non-horror Speculative Fiction be on-topic for this site?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/537/7957)
- [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/337/7957)
- [Does "Fantasy" include the supernatural? What about horror?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3368/7957)
- [Are questions about alternate history on or off topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/7957)
- [Are comic superheroes considered sci-fi?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/130/7957)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Identification questions are not on topic here because they "don't fit the Q&A format" but are on topic on several other sites because they fit the Q&A format there.

Sci Fi & Fantasy frequently answer identification questions purely from description. While they focus on books and film, they have no policy forbidding asking about games.