# Another way to deal with ID questions

Tags: discussion, game-identification

I have a particular unpopular opinion, when it comes to this site. I love game ID questions, and I don't think we should restrict them to requiring media artefacts. I know this has been well discussed, and my ship has passed; I respect the decision of the community. But..

we have other sites that accept these questions. And I find the ID questions we close would almost always be accepted on our sister sites, save for some formatting and editing. If I'm trying to remember a game based off memory, I try to pitch my question to the SciFi exchange. They take memory based questions, and its a game, so its almost always sci fi.

This made me wonder. Is there some way we could put more effort into forwarding these questions to SciFi, when it falls under their scope?

I'm not saying forward the question, pass the buck. I'm saying members of this community take ownership these questions, and forward them on, only when they are also contributing members of the other site.

Our cross-exchange experience with both communities could ultimately allow us to help these users that just want to find that one game from their early childhood.

With our cross-exchange experience, we would know when the question would be acceptable on the other side, and we could still be there on the other side to take some level of ownership on making sure the quality was suitable for a good SE question.

This would have the natural side effect of also providing the best resolutions for these questions. Regardless of your opinions, its clear they are currently a bit of a stain on our network. Its a guaranteed closed question, with the user just simply looking for help and having honest intentions. If we can forward the question to another exchange, and also guarantee the question is received well and even answered, isnt that what really matters?

Comment: Who are you suggesting should be responsible for doing this? You? Do you have other volunteers who are active both here and on Sci-Fi? Are you saying that active users here should become active on Sci-Fi so that we can send our questions there?

Comment: Note that SF&F is also listed as a place to go on our FAQ for Game ID that doesn't fit our criteria: [My game identification question was closed as off-topic. Where can I ask for help instead?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13525/28182)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no issues migrating off-topic questions over to any of our fellow network sites that want them, but this is really a question for those sites respective metas. If such a meta is made, and the SFF.SE community agrees they want our Science Fiction & Fantasy memory based Game Identification questions then I'm more than happy to migrate them.

In other words, I'd suggest you make a meta over at [SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/). If the community over there agrees they want those question, then make a meta over here letting the Arqade community know this.

> I'm not saying forward the question, pass the buck. I'm saying members of this community take ownership these questions, and forward them on, only when they are also contributing members of the other site.

As to this part, I don't think we should treat them different any other migration. Either we migrate them, or we don't. We shouldn't need to worry about "taking ownership" of these questions. If the questions aren't up to par, we shouldn't migrate them to begin with (unless, of course, the SFF Meta says to send them everything and they'll  deal with it).

Comment: [The relevant SFF meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13392/58193). In short we wouldn't mind having them sent to us, usual migration rules apply. However, I will note that formal migration isn't strictly necessary and personally I think a comment pointing the OP to us would be better.